# How can I recreate a dialog, including its whole content?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-alertdialog

In my app I have 2 tabs. Each tab showing a different Activity.

In activity_1 I manage a global array of strings - add and delete options are available.

In activity_2 I have an AlertDialog.
The dialog is created by calling the Activity's dialog's functions: onCreateDialog, onPrepareDialog.
The dialog shows a multiple-choice list and the list's source is the global array that activity_1 manages.

The problem: I would like to display the updated list in the dialog of activity_2, according to the changes made to the global array in activity_1. The problem is that the list is created in onCreateDialog, and this method gets called only once in the activity's lifecycle.

For example: If the global array contains: ["Banana", "Orange"] and in activity_1 I've just added: "Apple", and I clicked tab #2, I would like activity_2 to open the dialog and display in the dialog list: ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"].

I've tried to repopulate the list in: onPrepareDialog but with no success, it's just allowing me to decide which of the list items will be checked or not. Should I extend AlertDialog?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DialogInterface.OnShowListener` to update the dialog content every time it gets displayed.

Edit:
You will have to implement a listadpater and set the adapter to the builder.

In onPrepareDialog, get the listview `mAlertdlg.getListView()` and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on its adapter. Or just set the adapter once again `mAlertdlg.getListView().setAdapter(list)`

Comment: How can I update the list itself (add an item to the list for example) in onPrepareDialog?

Comment: I currently build the dialog's list by calling the AlertDialog.Builder.setMultiChoiceItems method when the dialog is created for the first time. How can I call the setMultiChoiceItems method again, after the dialog had been already created?

Comment: In that case u'll have to create the dialog again.

Comment: That's the thing, how can I re-create the Dialog?

Comment: Accepted. Couldn't call notifyDatasetChanged() though... the the ListAdapther doesn't seems to know this method... I ended up set the adapter over and over again... any idea how can I use notifyDatasetChanged()?